# ng2-material doesn't show icons

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, material-design, angular

I have an angular 2 with ng2-material for the view. Everything is apparently ok, even the log console, but it doesn't paint ng2-material icons.

Here is my code:

```
import 'zone.js/lib/browser/zone-microtask';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'babel-polyfill';

import {Component, View, ViewEncapsulation, enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES, MATERIAL_PROVIDERS} from "ng2-material/all";
import {COMPONENTS_DIRECTIVES} from "./app/all";

@Component({
  selector: 'app'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: 'app/home.html',
  styleUrls: [
    'node_modules/ng2-material/dist/ng2-material.css',
    'node_modules/ng2-material/dist/font.css'
  ],
  directives: [MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES,COMPONENTS_DIRECTIVES],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MainApp {
  constructor(){

  }
}

let appProviders = [
  MATERIAL_PROVIDERS
];

//enableProdMode();

bootstrap(MainApp,appProviders);
```

And here is that I see:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfcPs.jpg)

Comment: ng2-material is an 'unofficial' release. the official one has just started here :https://github.com/angular/material2
You'd better contact them on github

Comment: I am going to give a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, a workaround for it was: looking at the examples with the developer tools, showed that there is another class on these buttons, material-icons:

```
<i class="mdclass-dark material-icons"  md-icon >menu</i>
```

[image: looks like this for me...]

Answer (score 0):

This is not the official Angular2-material, however you can use it anyway.
did you apply its tab or attribute to your dom?

for example, to a button:

```
   <button md-raised-button name="btn1"></button>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to import the icons I think:

For me this line is added to one of my global css file:

```
@import '~https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
```